# Bootstrap tabs - text (heading) with underline

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Champs - Hope all you are doing great!!!

I need your help regarding bootstrap tabs. I am building a site, on which tabing is used. I searched for bootstrap tabs but there's little difference in my design.

Here is what I am searching for: 
[image]

[image]

should i convert bootstrap tabs into my design or there is another best way to achieve my desired results? Hope I am clear enough to explain my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the bottom border using the following selector:

```
.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: It means I have to modify bootstrap tabs to serve my design. Thanks as I am in hurry so will use your suggestions.

Comment: You haven't provided a real HTML (only images) - If you have a custom class for the tabs, then you can use it as a selector